# How to return nested document with Mongoose?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

If I have this collection

```
[
  {
    "_id": "637cbf94b4741277c3b53c6c",
    "text": "outter",
    "username": "test1",
    "address": [
      {
        "text": "inner",
        "username": "test2",
        "_id": "637cbf94b4741277c3b53c6e"
      }
    ],
    "__v": 0
  }
]
```

and would like to search for the nested document by `_id` and return all of the nested document. If I do

```
db.collection.find({
  _id: "637cbf94b4741277c3b53c6c"
},
{
  address: {
    $eq: {
      _id: "637cbf94b4741277c3b53c6e"
    }
  }
})
```

I get

```
query failed: (Location16020) Expression $eq takes exactly 2 arguments. 1 were passed in.
```

[Playground link](https://mongoplayground.net/p/koKFRuSpqob)

**Question**

Can anyone see what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use $elemMatch and also you have extra unneeded brackets. try

```
db.collection.find({
  _id: "637cbf94b4741277c3b53c6c",
  address: {
    $elemMatch: {
      _id: "637cbf94b4741277c3b53c6e"
    }
  }
})
```

Edit: if you only want to return the address add projection like this

```
db.collection.find({
  _id: "637cbf94b4741277c3b53c6c",
  address: {
    $elemMatch: {
      _id: "637cbf94b4741277c3b53c6e"
    }
  }
},
{
  _id: 0,
  address: 1
})
```

Comment: It also returns the parent, which I an not interested in.

Comment: @SandraSchlichting edited the answer to only select address

Comment: @SandraSchlichting and by the way are you using `find` on purpose? are there gonna be multiple documents with certain specifications? if not you could use `findOne` which returns a single document

Comment: Ahh yes, I should use `findOne()`. Your code works perfectly. Is it possible to only return the value, and not the `address` key also? Like this?: https://pastebin.com/C6xxBwLw

Comment: This solution will not work well if the array has more than 1 item...

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use find:

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  _id: 0,
  address: {
    $elemMatch: {
      _id: "637cbf94b4741277c3b53c6e"
    }
  }
})
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/eK3068IKdKG)

The other option is to use aggregation pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $in: [
          "637cbf94b4741277c3b53c62",
          "$address._id"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $replaceRoot: {
      newRoot: {
        $first: {
          $filter: {
            input: "$address",
            cond: {
              $eq: [
                "$$this._id",
                "637cbf94b4741277c3b53c6e"
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
])
```

See how it works on the [playground example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/FxRFOADz_Dt)